# Kill function after a given amount of time?

Tags: python, multithreading, timer, signal-processing

What's the best way to kill a function (that is still running) after a given amount of time in Python? These are two approaches I have found so far:

Say this is our base function:

```
import time
def foo():
    a_long_time = 10000000
    time.sleep(a_long_time)

TIMEOUT = 5 # seconds
```

**1. Multiprocessing Approach**

```
import multiprocessing

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = multiprocessing.Process(target=foo, name="Foo")
    p.start()

    p.join(TIMEOUT)

    if p.is_alive()
        print('function terminated')
        p.terminate()
        p.join()
```

**2. Signal Approach**

```
import signal

class TimeoutException(Exception):
    pass

def timeout_handler(signum, frame):
    raise TimeoutException

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)


signal.alarm(TIMEOUT)    
try:
    foo()
except TimeoutException:
    print('function terminated')
```

What are the advantages and disadvantages in terms of scope, safety and usability of these two methods? Are there any better approaches?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as always, it depends.

As you probably have already verified, both these methods work. I would say it depends on your application and correct implementation (your signalling method is a bit wrong...)

Both methods can be considered "safe" if implemented correctly. It depends if your main program outside the foo function needs to do something, or can it just sit and wait for foo to either complete or timeout. The signalling method does not allow any parallel processing, as your main program will be in foo() until it either completes or times out. BUT you need then to defuse the signal. If your foo completes in one second, your main program leaves the try/except structure, and four seconds later ... kaboom ... an exception is raised and probably uncaught. Not good.

```
try:
    foo()
    signal.alarm(0)
except TimeoutException:
    print ("function terminated")
```

solves the problem.

I would personally prefer the multiprocessing approach. It is simpler and does not require signals and exception handling that in theory can go wrong if your program execution is not where you expect it to be when a signal is raised. If it is ok for your program to wait in join(), then you are done. However, if you want to do something in the main process while you wait, you can enter a loop, track time in a variable, check if over timeout and if so, terminate the process. You would just use join with a tiny timeout to "peek" if the process is still running.

Another method, depending on your foo(), is to use threads with a class or a global variable. If your foo keeps processing commands instead of possibly waiting for a long time for a command to finish, you can add an if clause there:

```
def foo():
    global please_exit_now
    while True:
        do_stuff
        do_more_stuff
        if foo_is_ready:
            break
        if please_exit_now is True:
            please_exit_now = False
            return 
    finalise_foo
    return
```

If do_stuff and do_more_stuff complete in a reasonable amount of time, you could then process things in your main program and just set global please_exit_now as True, and your thread would eventually notice that and exit.

I would probably just go for your multiprocessing and join, though.

Hannu

Comment: Thanks for catch on the signal approach. I think I am planing on using the multiprocessing because of the opportunity for parallelism and simplicity.

Comment: In multiprocessing, remember to encapsulate your p.terminate() with try/except.  If your application is heavily used, it will eventually encounter a rare situation where p.join() timeouts as p is still running, p.is_alive() returns true, p finishes immediately after this, and when you call p.terminate() an exception will be raised as p is not running anymore. You can easily ignore the exception as the state of your application is what you want it to be (no p running), but if uncaught, your main program would exit at this point.

Comment: Actually, you don't need is_alive() check at all as it does not provide any additional, useful info as p could die between is_alive and your next command. Just call p.terminate() inside try/except and ignore exceptions. It either succeeds or fails, your p will be gone nevertheless.