# How to break 'for' loop when execution time exceeds 2 seconds

Tags: python

I have a nested for loop. I am trying to implement a function on a numpy array. Sadly, some data point are bad and start taking ram till system freezes. But, i can figure out those faulty indexes manually by interrupting the loop and removing that data.

The the best thing i can think of is executing a time bound 'for' loop where the loop exists when execution time exceeds, say 2 seconds.
here is a sample code for my implementation.

```
channel=6
for index in range(len(X_train)):
      for i in range(channel):
               X_train[index][:,channel] = function_that_creates_issue_for_some_index_values(X_train[index][]......)
```

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40915527/kill-function-after-a-given-amount-of-time) help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timeout on a function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492519/timeout-on-a-function-call)

Answer (score 1):

If a `function_that_creates_issue_for_some_index_values()` is stuck, it's two-way to break this

1. Add timeout mechanism in the `function_that_creates_issue_for_some_index_values()` and break it from the inside
2. Start `for index in range(len(X_train)):` loop as multiprocessing. Then you can start another process of monitoring that loop and break it when it gets stuck.

If only this loop get stuck `for i in range(channel):` not `function_that_creates_issue_for_some_index_values()`, just use @Othmane Messaoud solution

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import time
channel=6
for index in range(len(X_train)):
      start_time = time.clock()
      for i in range(channel):
          if (time.clock() - start_time > 2 ) :
              break;
```

Comment: This won't work if the program is stuck in the `function_that_creates_issue_for_some_index_values`

Comment: Thats a different problem of what your question were. I cant help if we cant see the function core

Comment: function core is much more elaborate and has over 200 lines of code. So, I believe that will be out of scope for you. It involves wavelet decompositions, fft, dwt, etc. @OthmaneMessaoud

Comment: Sorry, i wish i can help with that